# Quirk in calculating a percentage with a while loop

Tags: python

I am trying to do a quick percentage counter, as follow:

```
percentage = 1
while chunk:
    chunk = f.read(size/100)
    read += len(chunk)
    m.update(chunk)
    if size > 500000000:
        print '%s done for %s.'%(percentage, name)
        percentage += 1
```

This returns 102 print statements, [1,102], instead of what I am trying to do, [1,100]. The reason for this seems to be that it is doing a print statement on the first iteration (0 read) and also on the last iteration (100% read). What would be the simplest way to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not a simple off-by-one error.

Let's say the file is 199 bytes long. Each iteration will read `size/100` bytes, i.e. one byte. Consequently, the loop will execute 199 times, and "percentages" would range from 1 to 199.

Given that you only print out the percentages for large files, you won't actually see numbers as high as 199. Nonetheless, the logic is still flawed, as you have already observed.

A better way is to get rid of the `percentage` variable and use a direct computation instead:

```
while chunk:
    chunk = f.read(size/100)
    read += len(chunk)
    m.update(chunk)
    if size > 500000000:
        print '%s done for %s.'%(100.0 * read / size, name)
```